# Very slow login - Artix linux, s6

Tags: linux, authentication, arch, s6

I have just installed artix with s6 init, and it takes so many time (about 1m) to perform login in tty.

But it happens only for primary session of the tty. I mean, if I try to access another user through `su` and enter his password - it is going absolutely normal.

About the machine:

- NVMe SSD
- Ryzen 4500U

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps DNS isnt configured/working correctly on the server ? (just a stab in the dark, but doesnt sound unlikely)

I'd start by testing the DNS with dig or nslookup or the like, and otherwise checking the server logs for errors.